# limited number of rows in a page

Tags: php, javascript, sql, css

Hi I'm retrieving my data from DB 
my data is (pic & name ) when I retrieved them I put them in 4 columns 
now I wanna limit the number of rows in each page , I want each page shows three rows only 
and if there is more data I want to make it display in next page

my code :

```
    <?php
$items_in_row = 4 ;
$index = 0 ;
?>

<table>
  <tr>

<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result , MYSQL_ASSOC)){ 
  $index++ ; ?>
  <td>       
    <p>
      <img id='g1' src='/<?php echo $row["img"] ;?>' width=130 height=130 onClick='f1()'>
    </p>
    <p> Name: <?php echo $row['name'] ; ?> </p>
    <br>
  </td>
<?php if ($index%$items_in_row == 0){ ?>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<?php }
} ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: pagination - https://www.google.com/search?q=php+pagination

Comment: Pagination on SO: https://www.google.com/search?q=php+pagination+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 well played sir ... well played

Comment: http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use the LIMIT() function in SQL, passing in variables that you are storing in the session in PHP. Let's say you want 3 rows of 4 pictures on each page, then you want 12 pictures. So you do something like

```
select * from pictures LIMIT(0,12)
```

This returns the first 12 items.

You can do it by just tracking page number. Maybe you have a $page variable in your PHP. If you are on page 2, $page contains 2. Use that to construct a dynamic SQL query with your PHP maybe like this...

```
$sqlQueryStatement = "select * from pictures LIMIT(". ($page-1)*12 . ", 12)";
```

What this does is for page 2, it produces the sql statement:

```
select * from pictures LIMIT(12,12)
```

See how that works? Now you execute that SQL, and you have the set of results that should be output for page 2.

You can use some further logic to take these basic concepts and run with them...extending them to uses like creating the clickable pagination numbers on the bottom of your results and so forth.

Comment: I tried select * from pictures LIMIT 12 and it works , but the problem is that it gave me the first 12 pictures in the page but I need the rest of pictures display in other page , I mean if I have 12 pictures that's fine they will display in the first page , but if I have 24 pictures I will need 2 pages , and if I have 27 pictures I will need 3 pages and so on , but actually I have 14 pictures but I got only 1 page with the first 12 pictures

Comment: The way LIMIT works is you pass where you want to start first, then the number you want. So if you did select * from pictures LIMIT(12,12) you would get 12 pictures, starting with result 12.

Comment: well , when I put select * from pictures LIMIT(12,12) I got an error so I just replaced it with select * from pictures LIMIT 12

Answer (score 0):

i develop my pagination jobs using the following algorithm:

...1) selecting the results

```
$page = 1;   // what page to show, if you dont know 1 is default.
$maxthingsperpage = 5;   // how many things (etc. what you show) per page
$offset = ($page * $maxthingsperpage) - $maxthingsperpage;   // db id to start reading
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM things LIMIT ".$offset.",".$maxthingsperpage);
```

...2) display the things into page

```
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$numthingstodisplay = ($numrows > $maxthingsperpage ? $maxthingsperpage : $numrows);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result , MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   ... display here without worrying about when to break; num rows are exact
}
```

you can replace `$maxthingsperpage` with your `$items_in_row`

Comment: I tried your way , but I got this error message Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in line 103 , line 103 is $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);

Comment: are you sure the query is successful? i dont know your real query parameters but do some error checking like `if (!$result) { echo mysql_error(); }`

Comment: can you please tell me where I should put this code in my code exactly ?

Comment: the selection of results `(1)` must be put where you have the `$items_in_row = 4 ; ..` code. The display of results `(2)` must replace yours `while() { .. }`. This also means you `MUST` remove (or comment out) your original `"SELECT.. "` query which i cant see..